# Why in iOS14 (or at least iOS14.4) keyboardWillShowNotification is fired twice, while in iOS13 only one?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uikeyboard

Why in iOS14 (or at least iOS14.4 iPhone 12 simulator) keyboardWillShowNotification is fired twice, while in iOS13 only once?

My final goal is to make visible textfields that are hidden by the keyboard.

This is making my form to misbehave on iOS14 if I follow these steps:

1. Tap on the top most text field.
2. Scroll to the bottom.
3. Tap in the last text field.

Notice that the view is scrolled up to the previous tapped text field (in this case the top most one).

UI:
[image]

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
  
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    register()
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    unregister()
  }
  
  func register() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
                                           name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
                                           object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
                                           name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
                                           object: nil)
  }

  func unregister() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
  }

  @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)
    let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame?.size
    print("keyboardWillShow " + String(describing: keyboardSize))
    
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize!.height, right: 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
  }

  @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("keyboardWillHide")
    
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
  }
}
```

Output:

```
keyboardWillShow Optional((390.0, 336.0))
keyboardWillShow Optional((390.0, 336.0))
keyboardWillShow Optional((390.0, 336.0))
```

First output is when I tap the top most textfield.

Outputs 2 and 3 are when I tap the textfield at the bottom. Within these 2, the first one corresponds to the top most textfield and the second one to the textfield at the bottom.

And the scroll is automatically scroll to the the top most textfield instead of just not scroll at all because user had tapped the the textfield at the bottom.

Comment: It has always been the case that you might get a `keyboardWillShow` when the keyboard is already showing. It is up to you filter that out if it is unwanted.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug (or two) in iOS 14 (I'm testing on 14.3).

Try this for an example - it adds a full-size scroll view containing a vertical stack view with 8 text fields spaced 75-pts apart:

```
class KeyBoardTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 75
        
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        scrollView.addSubview(stack)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor),
            
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            
        ])
        
        for i in 1...8 {
            let tf = UITextField()
            tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
            tf.text = "\(i)"
            stack.addArrangedSubview(tf)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Notice there is **no** keyboard show/hide handling.

When you run that, tap in the top text field (with a "1" in it). The keyboard will show.

Now, without typing anything, scroll down... because we didn't adjust the scroll view's content inset, you'll only be able to scroll down to the 5th or 6th text field.

Tap in the lowest visible text field --- and the scroll view will scroll so the top text field is again visible, while "text field 5" is still the first responder.

If you scroll / tap / scroll / tap... the keyboard will remain visible but the *previous* first-responder text field will be scrolled into view.

However, as soon as you type anything in a field, everything returns to normal.

Now, we'll use that same class, but we'll add keyboard notification handling:

```
class KeyBoardTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    var firstTextField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 75
        
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        scrollView.addSubview(stack)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor),
            
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            
        ])
        
        for i in 1...8 {
            let tf = UITextField()
            tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
            tf.text = "\(i)"
            stack.addArrangedSubview(tf)
            if i == 1 {
                firstTextField = tf
            }
        }
        
        register()

    }

    func register() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
                                               object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
                                               object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)
        let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame?.size
        print("keyboardWillShow " + String(describing: keyboardSize))

        // only change scroll view insets if .bottom != keyboard height
        if scrollView.contentInset.bottom != keyboardSize?.height {
            print("setting insets")
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize!.height, right: 0.0)
            scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
            scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        }
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("keyboardWillHide")
        
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    }

}
```

We'll see the same (buggy) behavior... and we'll see the "double will show" notification firing. I added an `if` clause so we only change the content inset if the keyboard frame has changed, so we have ruled that out as the culprit.

Again, though, as soon as we type a character into any of the text fields, the *expected* behavior returns to normal -- ***AND*** we no longer get the "double will show" notifications.

Unfortunately, after trying several different things to *force* it, I haven't found a work-around :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks guys for your attention.

What we resolved, to minimise this behaviour, is to set the scroll view to dismiss the KB on drag. This will move the "double call" to the keyboard is hidden and not when it is shown.